# c++ realloc performance vs malloc

Tags: c++

First of all, I know that I'm wrong but I don't know what is my mistake.
According to [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/), about "realloc" it says that

> The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. If the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is indeterminate.

So if we use "realloc" if it wants to allocate new location to data, it will copy previous data to new location. So if this is true I'm curios to know isn't that better to use `free` + `malloc` instead of realloc? Because I think copying previous data to new location would not be a good idea when we consider about performance.

Can any one help me to find out that where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's rare that realloc would choose a new location and copy to it, although assuming a new location will never be chosen can lead to UB. It's probably best to just use realloc and ignore the minimal and rare performance consequence.

Comment: Major point of using `realloc` is to use the data in already allocated buffer as it is with some additional space. If you don't need to the existing data, then you may do `free + malloc` indeed. Manual copying would be worse in terms of performance as libc is very optimized and it may not even has to do copy if there is plenty of contiguous space which satisfy new allocation requirement.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? You shouldn't use malloc/realloc in C++ to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

Use `realloc` - It has a better idea of the structure of the heap and therefore will try to avoid doing the copy.

Doing the malloc/copy/free each time does not have this performance enhancement

Comment: why did you say "malloc/copy/free" because i don't need previous data any more so it would be "malloc/free".
and you mean that in the case that "realloc" need copy data , "malloc/free" would be a better approach?

Comment: @pooyan If you don't need the old data, why are you considering `realloc` at all? (And in C++, you should stay away from both `malloc` and `realloc`, anyway.)

Comment: consider i have a loop and in each iteration i need to allocate new location to get new data.

Comment: What happens to the old data? Why not just have a buffer on the stack?

Comment: when each iteration finished, i have processed that data so i do not need it and in the next iteration i just need to get new data and start processing it and this will continue.

Comment: Why use malloc at all? If you do just overwrite the memory

Comment: you know, because of my program logic i have to do that. I'm using cuda so it is some times happen that i have to use malloc. it is a bit hard to explain logic of my program:(. sorry .

Comment: @molbdnilo: If you don't know better, it might appear beneficial to have one library call instead of two.

Answer (score 4):

The justification of `realloc` is that it's faster than "2nd malloc, manual copy, free". As you suspect, a normal `free` and `malloc` would be faster, but that's because they do less.

PS. In C++, `realloc` is very dangerous because it fails to call copy constructors. OTOH, `std::vector::resize` does call copy constructors, default constructors and/or destructors.

Comment: I'm not sure "fails" is a fair description. It opts not to / doesn't even attempt to. You can't fail at something when that act was never your intention in the first place ;)

Comment: tanks for your answer. so you mean that if i don't need previous data, "malloc"+"free" would be better approach? am I right?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that multiple mallocs will be significantly faster than multiple reallocs.

As an example, assume that you wanted to grow memory by doubling each time. You could realloc a large chunk of memory.  Another approach would be to make multiple malloc calls to create a vector of memory chunks.

Take the following example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static const size_t INITIAL_MEMORY_SIZE = 2;
static const size_t NUM_ALLOCATIONS = 32;
static const size_t NUM_ITERATIONS = 100;

static void multiple_malloc() {
  size_t previous_size = 0;
  size_t current_size = INITIAL_MEMORY_SIZE;
  char* data[NUM_ALLOCATIONS];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ALLOCATIONS; i++) {
    data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * current_size);
    assert(data[i]);
    current_size += previous_size;
    previous_size = current_size;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ALLOCATIONS; i++) {
    free(data[i]);
  }
}


static void multiple_realloc() {
  size_t current_size = INITIAL_MEMORY_SIZE;
  char* mem = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ALLOCATIONS; i++) {
    mem = (char*)realloc(mem, sizeof(char) * current_size);
    assert(mem);
    current_size += current_size;
  }
  free(mem);
}


static void run_test(
  const char* test_name,
  void allocate()) {
  clock_t start = clock();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    allocate();
  }

  clock_t end = clock();
  printf("%s: ran in %lf seconds.\n",
     test_name, (end - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  run_test("multiple_malloc", multiple_malloc);
  run_test("multiple_realloc", multiple_realloc);

  return 0;
}
```

The multiple mallocs will be significantly faster than the multiple reallocs:

```
$ ./misc_perf_test
multiple_malloc: ran in 0.171875 seconds.
multiple_realloc: ran in 7.859375 seconds.
```

When creating a data structure such as a map or list where you might want to pre-allocate a chunk of elements, malloc will be much faster.